# How do i stop threading from inside of thread queue python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm in a situation where I need to stop executing a thread when it matches a condition inside of current running/executing thread:

Here's the example what i mean:

- We have list of 5 numbers from 1 to 5.
- We queued them & processing them along with10 Number of Thread in Run_Calc function.
- in `Run_Calc` i want my thread to stop if it matches a condition of `3`

```
import threading,queue

q = queue.Queue()
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]

for each_num in numbers:
    q.put(each_num)

def Run_Calc(no):
    print("NO IS : {}".format(no))
    if no == 3:
        print("YES I WANT TO EXIT HERE and DONT WANT TO EXECUTE 4,5")

def ProcessThreading():
    while not q.empty():
        get_number = q.get()
        Run_Calc(get_number)

th_list = []
for i in range(10):
    t = threading.Thread(target=ProcessThreading)
    th_list.append(t)
    t.start()
for th in th_list:
    th.join()
```

- OUTPUT:

```
NO IS : 1
NO IS : 2
NO IS : 3
YES I WANT TO EXIT HERE and DONT WANT TO EXECUTE 4,5
NO IS : 4
NO IS : 5
```

- How do I achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python close a thread on multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43683257/python-close-a-thread-on-multithreading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases threads may compete in terms "who will race more quickly" even if they were instantiated sequentially.
For your simple case use [`threading.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Event) object to synchronize threads on particular event:

```
import queue
from threading import Thread, Event

q = queue.Queue()
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for each_num in numbers:
    q.put(each_num)


def run_calc(num, e):
    print("NO IS : {}".format(num))
    if num == 3:
        e.set()
        print("YES I WANT TO EXIT HERE and DONT WANT TO EXECUTE 4,5")


def process_thread(e):
    while not q.empty():
        if e.is_set():
            break
        num = q.get()
        run_calc(num, e)


th_list = []

e = Event()
for i in range(10):
    t = Thread(target=process_thread, args=(e,))
    th_list.append(t)
    t.start()

for th in th_list:
    th.join()
```

Sample output:

```
NO IS : 1
NO IS : 2
NO IS : 3
YES I WANT TO EXIT HERE and DONT WANT TO EXECUTE 4,5
```