# Terminate peacefully if execution times goes beyond certain threshold using python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am trying to understand `Threadpool` library. Below is my sample code and it output is as follows:

Code:

```
import os
import time
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
class ProcessTest:
    def myfunct1(self,id, pid):
        print("Function 1 -", "Process ID - ", pid,": ","ID - ", id)

    def WorkerProcess(self, myId):
        self.myfunct1(myId, os.getpid())

    def StartWorkflow(self):
        myId = [1,2,3]
        pool = ThreadPool(len(myId))
        pool.map(self.WorkerProcess, myId)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

A = ProcessTest()
A.StartWorkflow()
```

Output:

```
Function 1 - Process ID -  24920 :  ID -  3
Function 1 - Process ID -  24920 :  ID -  2
Function 1 - Process ID -  24920 :  ID -  1
```

This shows that `pool.map` creates one system `Process` with PID = 24920 and executes WorkerProcess function in parallel for 3 myIds: 1,2,3.

Now,

```
If WorkerProcess function and myId = 1 it takes 10 seconds to complete.
If WorkerProcess function and myId = 2 it takes 5 seconds to complete.
If WorkerProcess function and myId = 3 it takes 5 seconds to complete.
```

How do I terminate execution peacefully for `WorkerProcess function and myId = 1` at 6th second itself rather than continuing its execution? Also, this termination should not harm processing for other ids -`WorkerProcess function and myId = 2 and 3`

Comment: Read [close-a-thread-on-multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43683257/python-close-a-thread-on-multithreading)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Timeout function if it takes too long to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281850/timeout-function-if-it-takes-too-long-to-finish)