# Join Threads running inside Tkinter.Tk().mainloop

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I am working with tkinter and within the `__init__()` method of my `Windows` class, where I launch two threads that execute a method.

My problem is that I can't figure out where to call `.join()` so that those threads don't continue their execution once the main window is destroyed through `Tk().destroy()` method.

Comment: ***call .join()so that those threads don continue***: `.join()` don't terminate a `Thread`. Read [terminate an Thread controlled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43686996/7414759)

Comment: When you create the Threads, make them "daemonic" before starting them. This will cause them to be automatically terminated when the main thread exits. It's mentioned in the [Thread documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread).

Answer (score 0):

`Tkinter.Tk().mainloop()` is blocks the program from continuing while the screen updates. After calling `Tk().destroy()`, it will unblock and continue the program as normal, allowing you to call `thread.join()` there. Here as a demo of for code executing after:

```
from tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()

def f():
    root.destroy()

root.after(3000,f)
root.mainloop()
print("Join Thread Here")
```